# Associative array in javascript using a pair/tuple as multi-value key/index

Tags: javascript, dictionary, associative-array

In python, I can use tuples as the key to a dictionary. What's the equivalent in javascript?

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[(1,2)] = 5
>>> d[(2,1)] = 6
>>> d
{(1, 2): 5, (2, 1): 6}
```

---

For those who are interested, I have two arrays...

`positions = ...`

`normals = ...`

I need to make a third array of position/normal pairs, but don't want to have duplicate pairs. My associative array would let me check to see if I have an existing `[(posIdx,normalIdx)]` pair to reuse or create one if I don't.

I need some way of indexing using a two-value key. I could just use a string, but that seems a bit slower than two numbers.

Comment: There isn't really one currently (an upcoming version of JavaScript is slated to include one) -- is there any particular reason to do so?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I mean, you could actually use a string representation of your tuple as a key to the array, but the thought of it is kind of painful. You could also use an actual 2 dimensional associative array as well as Stepan mentions in his answer. I think you'll get a better answer if you say what you are trying to do, and maybe show how you are using the above sort of datastructures.

Comment: Can there be multiple normals for any one position or vice versa?

Comment: @Jack yes, this is exactly the reason why I need the two-value key. My application needs position/normals on a 1 to 1 ratio, but the data gets bigger if I don't reuse existing pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript does not have tuples but you can use arrays instead.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[[1,2]] = 5
>>> d[[2,1]] = 6
>>> d
Object {1,2: 5, 2,1: 6}
```

Comment: Note this just uses the string representation of the array, that is, `d['1,2']` is the same as `d[[1,2]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

> The keys of an Object are Strings and Symbols, whereas they can be any
>   value for a Map, including functions, objects, and any primitive.

This will avoid a potential problem with the key just being a string representation of the array.

```js
d = {};
d[[1,2]] = 5;
d[[2,1]] = 6;
console.log("d[[1,2]]:", d[[1,2]]);
console.log("d['1,2']:", d['1,2']);

m = new Map();
ak1 = [1,2];
ak2 = [1,2];
m.set([1,2], 5);
m.set([2,1], 6);
m.set(ak1, 7);
console.log("m.get('1,2'):", m.get('1,2'));
console.log("m.get([1,2]):", m.get([1,2]));
console.log('m.get(ak1):', m.get(ak1));
console.log('m.get(ak2):', m.get(ak2));
```

Note that it uses a variable reference for the key, not the value.